# The limit of ${x^{x^x}}$ as $x\to 0^+$

Tags: limits

I wanted to determine the following:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x^{x^x}} &= 0
\end{align*}
There has been a previous question posted on it before but the arguments on there do not seem entirely formal: [Limit of ${x^{x^x}}$ as $x\to 0^+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439410/limit-of-xxx-as-x-to-0)

I wanted to see if we could use the fact that we know that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x^x} =1$

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x^{x^x}} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x^xlnx}=e^{{\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^xlnx}} $ but I can't see this helping me as $lnx$ has an infinite limit here.

Any thoughts as to how to get a nice solution to this?

Comment: I wouldn't say the limit of $\ln x$ as $x \to 0^+$ is indeterminate, but rather than it is $-\infty$.

Comment: Also $1\cdot(-\infty) =-\infty$

Comment: Are we allowed to say this? @kingW3

Comment: @user258521 Why not prove that rigorously as a nice exercise?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $a* \pm \infty$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is not an indeterminate form! 
Also notice that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln(x) = -\infty$

Hence:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x^{(x^x)}} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x^xlnx}=e^{{\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^xlnx}} = e^{{\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x * \lim_{x\to 0^+} lnx}} = e^{1*(-\infty)} = 0$$